# Can you be resident in several countries at the same time?

Tags: residency

During the same year sometimes you live in one country, sometimes in another, have apartment in both, driver licence and car in each country and pay taxes in both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each country defines what it means to be "resident", and for what purpose. Sometimes, a country will define residency as "present in the country for 183 days in a calendar year". Or "6 months", if less precise. Sometimes, a country might define residency as "registered with the local municipality as living in a house". Sometimes, residency for tax purposes is different than, say, residency for qualifying for reduced university tuition rates.

The general answer to your question is yes, you can almost certainly be considered "resident" in two or more places at once. Whether this will be beneficial or not, to you, would depend on which countries and your own personal circumstances.

Comment: for example USA and Canada. And they have tax treaty, so you avoid double taxation.